# Flutter: Access function in another class/file

Tags: flutter, dart

In the following set-up, how would I allow `fileb.dart` to access the function `reset` that is in `filea.dart`:

`filea.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.pink[200],
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: ''),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
{


  int testCount = 0;

  void test() {
    setState(() {
      testCount++;
    });
  }
```

`fileb.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './filea.dart';

class Buttons extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 11.0, top: 20),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: "btn1",
                onPressed: () => MyHomePageState.test(),
                child: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                splashColor: Colors.pink[900],
                backgroundColor: Colors.pink[200],
              ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

What do I need to change to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a function in another class unless it is `static`, and it should not deal with any variables that are `non-static`/`local` or it will through an error.

Another way to call a function is to pass it as an argument to the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through function callback.
Pass the test callback to ButtonWifget's `constructor` and use the callback in fab button onPressed as below mentioned sample code:

```
// In Button class 
Buttons({this.testCallback});
final Function testCallback;
 ...
 FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: "btn1",
                onPressed: testCallback,
)

// In MyHomePage class, pass the callback wherever you have used `Buttons` widget
Buttons(testCallback:test());
```

Hope this helps you :)